# GnuCash not starting after upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, gnucash

After upgrading to 2.4.11, GnuCash does not start on my XP machine.  I start it and nothing happens. Looking with *What's Running*, I see:

> gnucash-2.4.11-setup.exe
>   gnucash-2.4.11-setup.tmp
>   gnucash.exe
>   gconfd-2.exe

There is no activity shown for any of these programs. Any ideas why GnuCash locks up after upgrading would be helpful.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling runtime dependencies such as python, gtk+ (idk what gnucash uses tbh). Also, more often than not ported apps are usually more reliable in their 32 bit version. So grab those to save yourself some headaches if there is no compelling reason (performance) to use a 64 bit version.

Comment: Ярослав Рахматуллин thanks for the comment,  I have deleted and reloaded and no joy.  Mine being a Windows XP system, most of these come with the GNUcash download.

Comment: Hi All  Well I deleted the Gnucash dir (again) and downloaded 2.4.11(again) and it seemed to work.  At least it worked two or three times ant then my CPU died! After a new motherboard, CPU, memory, andWin 7, I downloaded the Win & version (64 bit) and all  seems well.    Thanks for your help Cliff

Comment: Since reinstalling worked, perhaps putting that as an answer would be a good idea?

Comment: Well it worked once or twice before, then quit, when I re-loaded it.  So I'm not sure if the last reload fixed it or the new OS, another reload and new motherboard did the trick.  Cliff